# Divide / split string based on spaces by n-value

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, algorithm, split

I'm trying to divide the string based on the spaces on the string, if I divide the string into a n value, the output should be array with 3 values

I have this string for example "SIZZLING STEAK TERIYAKI BOY" and I want to divide this string into 3 based on spaces, the output should be ["SIZZLING STEAK", "TERIYAKI", "BOY"];

Another example is my string is "POWERVILLE FUN RIDES" and if I will divide this into 2, the output should be ["POWERVILLE FUN", "RIDES"] and if I will divide this string into 3, the output should be ["POWERVILLE", "FUN", "RIDES"];

```
function getSplitedText(number, word) { 
 let splitedText = word.split(" ");
 let a = "";
 let b = [];
 let ctr = 1;
 for (let i = 0; i < splitedText.length; i++) {
  if (ctr === Math.ceil(splitedText.length / number)) {
   a += splitedText[i];
   b.push(a);
   a = "";
   ctr = 1;
 } else {
   a += splitedText[i] += " ";
   ctr++;
 }

 if (i === splitedText.length - 1) {
   if (a !== "")  b.push(a);
 }
}

return b;
}

let ans = getSplitedText(3, "SIZZLING STEAK TERIYAKI BOY");
document.write(ans)
```

Here is my current code for this one: https://jsfiddle.net/nesvcz1w/
on this fiddle the string "SIZZLING STEAK TERIYAKI BOY" became ["SIZZLING STEAK, TERIYAKI BOY"] which is wrong, it should be ["SIZZLING STEAK", "TERIYAKI", "BOY"];

Comment: `SIZZLING STEAK TERIYAKI BOY`. What if `number` here is negative? 0? 5?

Comment: @WiktorZychla You can only choose 1, 2 and 3, thanks

Comment: You mean first two words is one word but another not?

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi the output should be an array, the string that you can pass is any kind of string, the function that im trying to achieve is, it will split the string based on the spaces like str.split(" ") and the string should be divided into n-number

Comment: @Kevin: it's an argument, it can have any value. The question was how the system should respond to such values of the argument.

Answer (score 1):

At first we can split our string into array words. Let's call it `splitted`. Then we can make a decision based on `breaker` whether word should be concatenated or pushed as whole word:

```
fooDivider = (str, num) => {
    let splitted = str.split(' ');
    let breaker = (splitted.length - num) + 1;

    const joined = splitted.splice(0, breaker).join(' ');
    return [joined, ...splitted];
}
```

An example:

```js
let str = "POWERVILLE FUN RIDES";

fooDivider = (str, num) => {
   let splitted = str.split(' ');
   let breaker = (splitted.length - num) + 1;

   const joined = splitted.splice(0, breaker).join(' ');
   return [joined, ...splitted];
}

console.log(fooDivider("SIZZLING STEAK TERIYAKI BOY", 3));
console.log(fooDivider("POWERVILLE FUN RIDES", 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const splitText = (str, n) => {
  const strArray = str.split(" ");
  if(n === strArray.length) {
    return strArray;
  } else if(n < strArray.length) {
    const combine = strArray.slice(0, (strArray.length-n)+1)
    const defaultSet = strArray.slice((strArray.length-n)+1, strArray.length)
    return [...[combine.join(" ")], ...defaultSet]
  } else {
    return []
  }
}

const ans1 = splitText("SIZZLING STEAK TERIYAKI BOY", 3);
console.log("ans 1", ans1);
const ans2 = splitText("POWERVILLE FUN RIDES", 2);
console.log("ans 2", ans2);
const ans3 = splitText("POWERVILLE FUN RIDES", 3);
console.log("ans 3", ans3);
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will suit your needs.

```
  function getSplitedText(number, word) {
    var indexes = dotIndexes(word);
    let splitedText = word.split(" ");
    if (number == indexes.length + 1) {
      //full parse
      return splitedText;
    } else {
      //just latest ones
      let combinedParts = "";
      let partsOfResult = [number];
      for (let counter = 0; counter < splitedText.length; counter++) {
        var element = splitedText[counter];
        if (counter > 1) {
          partsOfResult[counter-1] = element;
          //console.log("seperate :" + splitedText[counter] + counter);
        } else {
          combinedParts += " ";
          combinedParts += element;
          //console.log("combine :" + splitedText[counter] + counter);
        }
      }
      combinedParts = combinedParts.trim();
      partsOfResult[0] = combinedParts;      
      return partsOfResult;
    }
  }
  function dotIndexes(word) {
    var indices = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      if (word[i] === " ") indices.push(i);
    }
    return indices;
  }
  var myWord = "SIZZLING STEAK TERIYAKI BOY";
  var myWord2 = "POWERVILLE FUN RIDES";
  console.log(getSplitedText(3, myWord));
  console.log(getSplitedText(4, myWord));
  console.log(getSplitedText(2, myWord2));
  console.log(getSplitedText(3, myWord2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may do like;

```js
function fun(t,n){
  var ws = t.split(/\s+/);
  return [].concat( ws.slice(0,n)
                      .join(" ")
                  , ws.slice(n)
                  );
}

var t1 = "SIZZLING STEAK TERIYAKI BOY",
    t2 = "POWERVILLE FUN RIDES";

console.log(fun(t1,2));
console.log(fun(t2,2));
```